# Circle selection in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have the follow 2 code snippets. I want to know why the second one won't generate four circles?

This one will generate four circles.

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
sampleSVG.append("circle").style("stroke", "gray").style("fill", "white").attr("r", 10).attr.("cx", 80).attr("cy", 70);
sampleSVG.append("circle").style("stroke", "gray").style("fill", "white").attr("r", 10).attr.("cx", 140).attr("cy", 130);
sampleSVG.append("circle").style("stroke", "gray").style("fill", "white").attr("r", 10).attr.("cx", 200).attr("cy", 190);

var circle = sampleSVG.selectAll("circle").data([32, 57, 112, 293]);
var enter = circle.enter().append("circle");
enter.attr("cy", 90)
     .attr("cx", 160)
     .attr("r", function(d){return Math.sqrt(d);});

circle.style("fill", "steelblue");
```

This one will not generate four circles. Only three circles are shown.

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
sampleSVG.append("circle").style("stroke", "gray").style("fill", "white").attr("r", 10).attr.("cx", 80).attr("cy", 70);
sampleSVG.append("circle").style("stroke", "gray").style("fill", "white").attr("r", 10).attr.("cx", 140).attr("cy", 130);
sampleSVG.append("circle").style("stroke", "gray").style("fill", "white").attr("r", 10).attr.("cx", 200).attr("cy", 190);

var circle = sampleSVG.selectAll("circle");
circle.data([32, 57, 112, 293]);
var enter = circle.enter().append("circle");
enter.attr("cy", 90)
     .attr("cx", 160)
     .attr("r", function(d){return Math.sqrt(d);});

circle.style("fill", "steelblue");
```

I don't know why they have different result. Shoudn't **var circle = sampleSVG.selectAll("circle").data([32, 57, 112, 293]);** be the same as **var circle = sampleSVG.selectAll("circle");**
    **circle.data([32, 57, 112, 293]);**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is that you're not saving the result of the call to `data()` in the second code snippet. This call returns a selection, but you're not saving it in a variable. `circle` is still only the result of your earlier selection, so `.enter()` is empty.

Comment: Got you. Just changed it to: circle = circle.data([32, 57, 112, 293]);